# How do I list all packages from unstable / experimental?

Tags: debian, packages, apt

I'm running a Debian testing system with some packages installed from unstable or experimental, using apt pinning.

**How can I list all packages that come from unstable or experimental?**
I'd like to use apt, but I have aptitude and synaptic installed as well.

Comment: The easiest way I found so far relies on the apt-show-version package: `apt-show-version | grep /unstable` or `apt-show-version | grep /experimental`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One option is to install `apt-show-versions`. For example, to find packages installed from unstable:

```
$ apt-show-versions | grep unstable
```

Also, the following script might be of interest: [A script to check how mixed your system is](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tyybbi/scripts/master/distrostate).

Comment: +1 for the script still working in 2021

Answer (score 9):

Using `aptitude` you can run the following command:

```
$ aptitude versions '~VCURRENT (~Aunstable|~Aexperimental) !~Atesting' --group-by=none
```

This will list all packages whose currently installed version (`~VCURRENT`) comes from the *unstable* or *experimental* archives (`~A`) and are not present in the *testing* archive (`!~A`). The `--group-by=none` option serves to produce a more terse output.

Comment: For some reason, that doesn't work for me. It gives me a huge list of packages which are most definitely not from unstable or experimental. The apt-show-version method above gives me the correct output. Can somebody else confirm?

Comment: Sorry, updated the answer, now should work properly.

Comment: Yes, now it works!

Comment: I'm unable to adapt this to filter out packages coming from 'stable' as well, neither to only pick packages coming from 'testing'. I guess I'll never understand how aptitude (or APT for that matter) works.